# Loading an Array Image item using the formatted NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I want to load an image from an array and set the view to display this image.

The current code isnt loading anything, just a gray image full screen.

`myView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[names objectAtIndex:r]]`

If I have a counter r, which I use to access the index. How could it be done to load an image as such

```
myView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
```

but using r as the placeholder for the number, in this case 3.

If I have images 1.png to e.g. 10.png and want to use the r which I already increment and decrement, ow could I call the correct image using a formatted string in the place of

@"3.png" ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
myView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", r]];
```

Comment: +1 or perhaps "%d" instead of "%@", if `r` is an int instead of an `NSNumber`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. 

It crashes the app. 

The r counter works correctly, and if I hardcode e.g.
myView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"];

or any other image in the same manner, it works perfectly. 
As well as loading from the array of images doens't work correctly either.
Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you , replied earlier before refreshing in the other comments. 
The @ was crashing the app, tried the %d and everything works perfect. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: just got back to this page sure. I will do that. :)